# How to manage recent, best, most etc viewed searches in java web application?

Tags: java, javascript

I need to manage and track the recently viewed, best rated and most popular docs/searches, and the application uses java and javascript.

Currently I plan to add a custom cookie and pull the search string from the same, but as I see that all the major sites like **amazon, flipkart** (e-commerce or stores), manage this information too..

I wish to check whether **there is any framework for this**? I looked around but no luck..

Any body has some idea or suggestion that can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case some body is looking for something similar:

I implemented an ajax implementation to get the required information, and then stored the same in the cookies of the browser per session, and then implemented js to get the data from the cookies.

I ensured that I cleanup the aforementioned cookies post logout.